# sync: chgrp <dir/file> failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, rsync

Trying to sync two directories with the command

```
sudo rsync -avh --progress /src/ /dst/
```

It gives the error:

```
sync: chgrp <dir/file> failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I understand `-a` is trying to preserve the permissions and the owners/groups (intended), but shouldn't running the command with `sudo` give rsync the permission for `chmod/chown/chgrp`?

Comment: Is `/dst/dir/file` on a *local* or *remote* or *fuse* file system? Are there security modules  like apparmar, SELinux, SMACK... enabled?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas source and destination are both on a remote server, accessing it via ssh. I don't have information on the security modules.

Comment: If it's sshfs, then files are accessed on the remote host using the credentials of the user you ssh'ed as there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Had to do a quick search for sshfs, that should only be used for remote mounting? If I've only logged into the remote with ssh, but running rsync on the logged in server within itself, it should still perform the instruction as superuser because of sudo. Is that correct?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas using the command without sudo had given error for `mkdir` with `Permission Denied`. Using sudo solved it, but failed the 'chgrp' command

Comment: By "local" I meant local to the machine you're running that rsync command in. Is `/dst/dir/file` on a filesystem local to the machine you're running that rsync command on? What's  the output of `df -T /dst/dir/file` (assuming GNU df)?